When I change the height of my browser window, my container stays in a static position. I want it to move with everything else
enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description hereI have a video that shows what is happening, although it doesn't appear that I am able to upload videos. Only images. I posted a series of screenshots that gradually change the window size. It won't allow me to post some of the screenshots due to the size of the image.
When I drag down the window height, the top two containers move with it, but the container beneath them remains in the same place which causes them to overlap. In addition, the bottom container also changes position when I change width of the window, which also causes it to overlap with the container above.
The top two containers react exactly how a typical webpage would respond when resizing you browser window.
This is the code I have for the bottom container:
HTML
`<section id="products">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Preview Products (* Will change this *)</h2>
    
    <p>
      * Brief description of I Am Vida, when and how it started, and where we are headed*
    </p>

    <article>
      <div>[[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/NyruM.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/aEksO.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/70Sur.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/ZgLJB.png)
        <img src="./images/IAM2.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Rose Water Hydrasol</h2>
        <p>
          * ITEM DESCRIPTION *
        </p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </article>
    
    <article>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Monster Repellent</h2>
        <p>
          * ITEM DESCRIPTION *
        </p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./images/IAM5.jpeg">
      </div>
    </article>
    
    <article>
      <div>
        <img src="./images/IAM1.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Hair Growth Oil</h2>
        <p>
          * ITEM DESCRIPTION *
        </p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>   
`

CSS

`section#products {

}

section#products .container {
  width: 56%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

section#products .container h2 {
  color: var(--color-dark);
}

section#products .container a {
  color: grey;
}

section#products .container > h2, section#products .container > p {
  text-align: center;
}

section#products article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

section#products article p {
  margin: 1.5 rem 0 1rem;
}

section#products article:last-child {
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
}

section#products article:last-child .image {
  margin-right: -8rem;
}

section#products a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}`

I have tried adding and changing the display property in "section#products", as well as adding and changing the position property. I've tried every possible combination of the two. I expected that if I have the same display as the previous containers, that this container would act in the same manner.
I've also tried setting the margin, margin right and left, and margin top and bottom, to auto. I saw on a different post that someone wanted the opposite to happen, so that their container would stay in the same place when the window is resized, and they originally had their margin set to auto.
